# Making UITextField in prototype cell first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have set up the textfield with a tag and user interaction disabled in a prototype cell.

This is how I have created the cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

..
..
..
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressgesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LongPressgesture:)];
[longPressgesture setMinimumPressDuration:2.0];
[cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer: longPressgesture];
UITextField *toDoTextField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
toDoTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
return cell;
}
```

then I would like to edit the textfield after a long press. So I have this:

```
- (void)LongPressgesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    }

    else {
        UITableView* tableView = (UITableView*)self.view;
        CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
        NSIndexPath* row = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
        NSInteger rowRow = [row row];
        UITextField *toDoTextField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:rowRow];    
        toDoTextField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [toDoTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

When I trigger the long press though only the last cell will work.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I would like to be able to long press on any cell and then edit the text.

Thank you if you can help.

Comment: Debug your use of `tag`. Is it actually set (are the cells being reused and your logic is invalidated)?

Comment: I debugged the tag for the toDoLabel with this :    toDoTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
    NSLog (@" \n\n toDoLabel.tag  %ld\n\n",(long)toDoTextField.tag); and they are being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the long press gesture recognizer to the table view *not the cell*:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
[self.myTableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Then handle it like this:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
      return;

    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.myTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (!indexPath)
        NSLog(@"Long press was on tableView, but not on a row");
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Long press on table view @ row %d", indexPath.row);
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSAssert(cell, @"Cell must be found");
        if (!cell)
           return;

        UITextField *toDoTextField = 
                     (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];    

        NSAssert(toDoTextField, @"UITextField must be found by tag");
        if (toDoTextField)
        {
           [self.tableView endEditing:YES];
           toDoTextField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
           [toDoTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the line: recognizer.delegate = self; though I get a warning 
Assigning to 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ToDoListViewController *const __strong'

Comment: If I just used [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer]; would that work or should I create: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView; in the .h and then use your code?

Comment: There is no need to assign self as the recognizer delegate if you aren't going to handle the `UIGestureRecgonizerDelegate` methods. If you are you'll want to implement one or more of the delegate methods.

Comment: @GerardGrundy There is no need to create a property for the recognizer -- when you assign it to the tableView that will hold a reference to it.

Comment: Ok I have tried the above code though it still just makes the last item in the list becomefirstresponder.

Comment: @GerardGrundy You are selecting the wrong row somehow. If you implement the code as-written you will see in your log statements that the correct row is being selected by the long press.

Comment: Yes that part is working but for some reason it's only working on the last row?  I'll have another look.

Comment: @GerardGrundy Do the NSLog statements show the correct row or not?

Comment: @GerardGrundy Updated code to show exactly how to select the correct cell.

Comment: @GerardGrundy Also note I've removed the unneeded `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` assignment.

Comment: Great that works but I can't select the first row.  Sorry the late answer been dealing with kids and rashes they have contracted from kindy. For some reason my row 0 will not allow itself to becomeFirstResponder

Comment: @GerardGrundy Must be something else you are doing in your code. Everything works fine.